# Setting to use matlab `integral` with a (only) scalar function?

Tags: matlab

I have a function which cannot be easily written easily to take a vector input and return a vector output.  The builtin `integral` function seems to expect this, and is evaluating a number of locations at the same time.  Is there any way to turn this off?

i.e., the simplest test case is

```
f = @(x) x * x; % intended to be univariate
integral(f, 0, 1); %I only want to have it call with univariate inputs.
```

where I am purposefully not setting the function to be `x .* x` in order to test the univariate input.  Obviously, my function is a lot more complicated than this and cannot be vectorized.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the array-valued flag that's mentioned in the [help](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/integral.html):

```
>> f = @(x) x * x;
>> integral(f,0,1,'ArrayValued',true)

ans =

    0.3333
```

The help description is a bit misleading:

> Array-valued function flag, specified as the comma-separated pair
>   consisting of `'ArrayValued'` and either `false`, `true`, `0`, or `1`. Set this
>   flag to `true` to indicate that `fun` is a function that **accepts a scalar
>   input and returns a vector, matrix, or N-D array output.**
>
> **The default value of `false` indicates that `fun` is a function that
>   accepts a vector input and returns a vector output.**

So notice that it doesn't explicitly specify that the input is a scalar and the output is a scalar, but it's clear the intent is to use scalar input.

Comment: Thanks.  I was a little confused on the `ArrayValued` when I looked it up.  I was under the impression it said that the `f `function returned a vector?  Is this exactly what it is for?

Comment: Yes, it is normally for using functions that accept scalars and return vectors, since those usually aren't vectorized to accept vectors and return matrices. In your case, just consider the result a 1-dimensional vector.

Comment: Makes perfect sense. Thanks